# Reactor - Stop source when first empty

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a requirement like this.

```
Flux<Integer> s1 = .....;

s1.flatMap(value -> anotherSource.find(value));
```

I need a way to stop this s1 when `anotherSource.find` gives me first empty. how to do that?

Note:

One possible solution is to throw error then capture it to stop.
`anotherSource.find(value).switchIfempty(Mono.error(..))`

I am looking for better solution than this.

Comment: Other option is to define some sort of empty object and then use the `takeWhile` operator: `s1.flatMap(value -> anotherSource.find(value).defaultIfEmpty(MY_SPECIAL_EMPTY_OBJECT)).takeWhile(i -> i != MY_SPECIAL_EMPTY_OBJECT)`

Comment: another hack.. good. so there is no specific operator!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't find a specific operator for this, you'll have to combine operators to achieve it. (Note that doesn't make it a "hack" per-se, reactive frameworks are generally intended to be used in a way where you combine basic operators together to achieve your use-case.)

I would agree that using an error to achieve is far from ideal though as it potentially disrupts the flow of *real* errors in the reactive chain - so that should really be a last resort.

The approach I've generally taken in cases where I want the stream to stop based on an inner publisher is to materialise the inner stream, filter out the `onComplete()` signals and then re-add the `onComplete()` wherever appropriate (in this case, if it's empty.) You can then dematerialise the outer stream and it'll respond to the completed signal wherever you've injected it, stopping the stream:

```
s1.flatMap(
        value ->
            anotherSource
                .find(value)
                .materialize()
                .filter(s -> !s.isOnComplete())
                .defaultIfEmpty(Signal.complete()))
    .dematerialize()
```

This has the advantage of preserving any error signals, while also not requiring another object or special value.